# JOptionPane not displaying correctly?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Today I updated my jdk and docs from 7 to 8. I made a few changes to my program, and now when I try to have the program use JOptionPane, JLabel, ..., everything messes up. I made a separate tester class whose sole purpose is to run a single JOptionPane box and the error still occurred. Below is a picture of what the dialog box looks like. Is there something seriously wrong with Java 8?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



public class CirclePointTester
 {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the x coordinate of the circle");
            int xc = Integer.parseInt(input);
        String input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the y coordinate of the circle");
            int yc = Integer.parseInt(input2);
        String input3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the height value of the circle");
            int height = Integer.parseInt(input3);
        String input4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the width value of the circle");
            int width = Integer.parseInt(input4);
    }
 }
```

[image: Program 1]

[image: Program 2]

Comment: better to share code as well.

Comment: The code doesn't seem to be the issue... my current IDE is JCreator Pro if that helps.

Comment: then there is something wrong with your operating system's graphics.

Comment: ...but it worked before I installed Java 8. Hmmm...

Comment: yes Java 8 can cause the issue. Install it again.

Comment: try setting a different look and feel
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.xxx);

Comment: Changing the LookAndFeel didn't work either...

Comment: Is that the real frame on the pictures? What OS are you using?

Comment: See [Initial threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Despite most of times there's no issue, the correct way when working with Swing is create and display components in the context of the Event Dispatch Thread, using in this case `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`

Comment: Err... I just opened up a different java-based IDE, Dr. Java, and all of the buttons in it have similar issues. I'm convinced it's something to do with Java 8.

Comment: So I uninstalled java 8, rebooted computer, and installed java 7... everything works fine. Conclusion: Java 8 is bad.

Comment: It could be a driver issue

Comment: @user2154420: It is working fine, on `Windows 7 Home Premium`, with `java version "1.8.0_05" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)`

Comment: @user2154420 read my comment in trashgods answer here, there is required steps, the guide

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reference, here's a complete example that shows no regression on Mac OS X 10.9, Java 8. It may help you pin down the apparent regression.

Addendum: In helpful comments, @mKorbel cites a [number of similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bjava%5D%20%5Bswing%5D%20nvidia) with Java 8 on Windows with certain NVIDIA cards.

[image]

Console:

```
42
```

Code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24875960/230513
 */
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "Enter the x coordinate of the circle");
                int xc = Integer.parseInt(input);
                System.out.println(xc);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: there is an issue with latest [Java7/8 versions on laptops, in Java8 on PCs too) on nVidia GPU card](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bjava%5d%20%5bswing%5d%20nvidia)