# Why is javax.swing.JOptionPane display messed up?

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem with JAVA GUI (I'm using eclipse) , the texts are not complete in the dialog window . look at the picture

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23715057/java-joptionpane-text-unreadable)?

Comment: As well as [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873504/joptionpane-not-displaying-correctly). Does your computer use an nVidea graphics card by chance?

Comment: yes , I'm using nVidea graphic card .

Comment: Did the duplicate fix it?

Comment: I found a solution which is right click on the eclipse.exe icon and go to run with graphic processor and choose nVidea processor high performance and it worked fine for me . but there is a new problem , I can't set the nVidea graphic card as the default graphic card for eclipse even when I've choosen it from the nVidea control panel which I run it as administrator .I have to choose it manually every time I want to run eclipse . I I really need your help to fix this problem .