# Java Swing: JLabel´s Text / Font shown incompletely

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I want to show some kind of information in a `JTreeTable` and start off with a `JDialog`, where something is written in `JLabels` (i think, that's the more unimportant fact).

The problem is, that my JLabel is not shown correctly, there are missing some details (see picture).

[image]

I already tried out three kinds of solution:

1.) Working with `Runnable`,`.setLookAndFeel`, and `.invokeLater`:

```
public NoDataWarningView() {
    Runnable gui = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager
                        .getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Some kind of text or information.",
                    "Warning",                        
                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

        }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(gui);
}
```

2.) Renew the font, before the text is written. It works, but the "OK!" from the button is still missing. [Referenced Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434845/setting-the-default-font-of-swing-program)

```
public static void setUIFont (javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource f){
    java.util.Enumeration keys = UIManager.getDefaults().keys();
    while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
      Object key = keys.nextElement();
      Object value = UIManager.get (key);
      if (value != null && value instanceof javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource)
        UIManager.put (key, f);
      }
}
```

3. Deleted a Font-File, because it seems, Java-Fonts were corrupt with Windows-Fonts and restarted. Had no effect. [Referenced Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115028/jlabel-text-is-garbled)

> To rebuild the cache: as administrator, delete this file and reboot the PC:
>
> del %WINDIR%\System32\FNTCACHE.DAT

Somebody has a clue concerning the solution?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22737535/230513); reference [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24875960/230513).

Comment: You're right, i didn't see that one. Could be merged with comments that the three ways above didn't help.

Comment: Thanks; sometimes it's hard to distinguish driver vs. synchronization problems. Let me know if this question needs to be re-opened.

Comment: The downgrade to JDK 1.7 was successful! So it does not need to be reopened.